# was just here / has just been here

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

> He **was just here, but** he has gone away.
>
> He **has just been here, but** he has gone away.

Which sentence is idiomatic? I suppose the first one because we need to show the difference in his location.

Comment: Why aren't you considering other combinations? *He was here, and he went away* or *He had been here, and he went away*

Comment: _He was here just now, but he has gone away_.

Comment: @Andrew Tobilko, I suppose your combinations aren't used if "he" changed his location  2 minutes ago and we need to emphasize it.